# Pass multiple variable to Tweepy api.update_status

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm attempting to pass multiple variables to the api.update_status function of Tweepy. I am attempting to call two variables from a Cursor, when I do it will only output one variable.

```
for (id, tweet_id, screen_name, created_at, text) in cursor:
url='https://www.threatminer.org/host.php'
payload={'q': text, 'api': 'True', 'rt': '6'}
headers={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
r=requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
json_data=r.json()
status_message=json_data['status_message']
status = text and "Was found in a Tweet"
if "Results found." in status_message:
    api=tweepy.API(auth)
    api.update_status(text, screen_name)
    print(text, screen_name)
    print(r.url)
    print json_data
else:
    print('Nothing')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "passing multiple variables to api.update_status"? Do you have two or more variables containing the text you want to send?

Comment: @RodrigoLeite That is correct. I have multiple variables containing text that I want to send.

Comment: I submitted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in your comment, you have multiple variables containing the text you want to send. To solve this problem, you need to concatenate them to form one single string.

If you're using Python 3.6+ you have the option of using formatted strings, like so:

```
string1 = "My name is"
string2 = "dog!"
string3 = f"{string1} {string2}"
```

In this case, `string3` will equal to `My name is dog!`. However, if you're not on Python 3.6+ you'll need to use the `format()` function to do this, like so:

```
string1 = "My name is"
string2 = "dog!"
string3 = "{} {}".format(string1, string2)
```

Another option is to use the `+` operator, but that's frowned upon for performance reasons.